# how to get if the user is page admin on facebook fan page custom tab

Tags: php, facebook, tabs, admin, fan-page

I am developing a tab based Facebook application that lets the users add custom tab to their page. I want to add a link for page admins to edit the tab, but the problem is how to get if the logged in user is a page admin?
I know how to do this is the old API, which are to be deprecated soon. I am using the new Graph API and new JavaScript SDK.
Don't know how to do it with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the fb_sig_is_admin parameter which is 1 when the user is an admin.

Unfortunately you won't know who the user is with a tab until they interact, so the usefulness of the Graph API is limited.

Comment: I am not able to get this parameter in the signature.

Comment: I seem to remember you need to disable OAuth 2.0 for Canvas in order to get fb_sig_is_admin. You might have to play with the Advanced settings.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a better way for that, a few days ago FB started supporting iframe on tabs,

From the facebook documentation

> Blockquote
>   When a user navigates to the Facebook Page, they will see your Page Tab added in the next available tab position. Broadly, a Page Tab is loaded in exactly the same way as a Canvas Page. When a user selects your Page Tab, you will received the signed_request parameter with one additional parameter, page. This parameter contains a JSON object with an id (the page id of the current page), admin (if the user is a admin of the page), and liked (if the user has liked the page). As with a Canvas Page, you will not receive all the user information accessible to your app in the signed_request until the user authorizes your app.
>   Blockquote

This is the URL:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/#tabs